# English text to it's “online slang” equivalent

Tags: translation

I'm looking for the translation of 28 short sentences to their "online" equivalent which can not be found by simply using a dictionary (The big text is mostly context clarification)

The forms that are used on websites and in applications are translated different in this "online" context (For example: On a website, the button "OK" in English, if it will be translated using a Romanian dictionary, will be translated to "Bine" which has the meaning: "I'm doing well" or "I accept what you proposed". In an application or online form, this translation is wrong, thus confusing the user. In an application, a good translation for the word "OK" in Romanian language would be "Continua" which implies that the user can go to the next step, and using "Continue" in English is counter intuitive because users are accustomed to buttons displaying "OK" as text if they no longer need to enter any data in the next step. So this is why i'm looking for translation to the "online" equivalent.)

These texts are for a mobile/online application that helps the users manage their passwords.

I'm looking for the "online" use of these texts/words applicable for the context i will define as "(CONTEXT:...)" and between () after each sentence that i look to be translated. The text explaining the context and the text in () doesn't need to be translated, it's there to specify what the text must express when translated.

If you do have the choice to use a short version for translation (Example: "Enter your password" versus "Enter the password that belongs to you") without sacrificing the meaning, please use the short version.

The texts help the user navigate and use the application. These are text for buttons and text form fields.

Thank you very much.

(CONTEXT: The user opens the application for the first time, he didn't read any instructions yet. There is a field where he can enter the password of his choice to be used later in the application for generating other passwords, this can be any password but to avoid confusion i will ask for his password. After he enters his password he clicks a "OK" button to go the next step. On the same page there is a text explaining how the password will be used)

**1.Text to be translated: "Enter your password"**

(Hint for the password field - It has to specify "your", implying that the password belongs to the user, it is his password that he must enter.)

**2.Text to be translated: "OK"**

(After entering the password the user will press this button to submit the form and continue)

**3.Text to be translated: "Account passwords will be generated depending on the password you enter here"**

(Account refers to an online account like Gmail or DropBox - username and password. The password for his account is generated by computing it)

**4.Text to be translated: "Password can not be empty"**

(Error message displayed in case the user clicks the "OK" button without entering any password)

(CONTEXT: The user is now presented with a screen that shows a message telling him how to add a new account. After he enters an account, a list containing the name of the accounts is shown to him. He can delete or edit the account details by pressing for a long time on the account name)

**5.Text to be translated: "My Accounts"**

(Title of the page - Letting the user know that he is now on the page where his accounts are shown)

**6.Text to be translated: "To add a new account, click on the Menu button and select "Add account"**

(Help message letting the user know how he can add a new account)

**7.Text to be translated: "Edit"**

(The user can press this button in order to edit the details of the account - username and internet address)

**8.Text to be translated: "Delete"**

(The user can press this button in order to delete the account from the list)

**9.Text to be translated: "Help"**

(Menu button that leads the user to a new page showing him instructions on how to use the application. English aliases: instructions)

**10.Text to be translated: "Add account"**

(Menu button that lets the user add a new account in the list)

**11.Text to be translated: "Settings"**

(Menu button that lets the user change preferences like password lenght. English aliases: preferences)

**12.Text to be translated: "Save"**

(Menu button that lets the user save his input)

**13.Text to be translated: "Copy"**

(Menu button that lets the user copy the password to his clipboard)

**14.Text to be translated: "Cancel"**

(Menu button that lets the user cancel any changes he has made)

**15.Text to be translated: "Close"**

(Menu button that lets the user close/dismiss an alert dialog)

**16.Text to be translated: "Open website"**

(Menu button that lets the user open a website page address that is shown on screen)

**17.Text to be translated: "New account"**

(Title of the page, letting the user know he is now in the place where he is adding a new account)

**18.Text to be translated: "Account name:"**

(Text that lets the user know that he is supposed to fill in an account name. Example: "johndoe" or "johndoe@example.com")

**19.Text to be translated: "Internet address:"**

(Text that lets the user know that he is supposed to fill in an internet address. Example: "google.com")

**20.Text to be translated: "Password:"**

(Text that lets the user know that what follows after ":" is a password)

**21.Text to be translated: "Edit account"**

(Title of the page, letting the user know he is now in the place where he is editing the account)

**22.Text to be translated: "Password strength:"**

(Text that lets the user know that the number that follows is the strength/length of a password. Can also be translated from "Password length" which is more common.)

**23.Text to be translated: "Account Name can not be empty!"**

(Error message displayed in case the user clicks the "Save" button without entering any name for the account)

**24.Text to be translated: "Account added. Long click on it to edit"**

(Alert displayed to the user to let him know that the account was added to the list and that he must click on its name for a longer period of time in order to edit it)

**25.Text to be translated: "Password copied to clipboard"**

(Alert displayed to the user to let him know that the password he was seeing was copied to the clipboard after he clicked "Copy")

**26.Text to be translated: "Account deleted"**

(Alert displayed to the user to let him know that the account was deleted from the list after he chose to delete it)

**27.Text to be translated: "Account updated"**

(Alert displayed to the user to let him know that the account details where updated successfully after he edited them and clicked "Save")

**28.Text to be translated: "Preferences updated"**

(Alert displayed to the user to let him know that the preferences from the settings screen where updated successfully after he edited them and clicked "Save". English aliases: Settings saved, settings updated, preferences saved)

Comment: This question was cross posted in Chinese.stackexchange, French.stackexchange, Italian.stackexchange *and* German.stackexchange. It's off-topic by any standards, contradicts in spirit and letter the rules of any SE networt and received an upvote here?! Shame I cannot downvote.

Comment: @c.p. Possibly upvoted by someone who's ignorant of the basic premises of the se network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Text to be translated: "Enter your password"

请输入密码

2.Text to be translated: "OK"

确定

3.Text to be translated: "Account passwords will be generated depending on the password you enter here"

您的账户密码会由您输入的密码产生

4.Text to be translated: "Password can not be empty"

密码不能为空

5.Text to be translated: "My Accounts"
我的账户

6.Text to be translated: "To add a new account, click on the Menu button and select "Add account"

要添加一个新账户，点击菜单键并选择“添加账户”

7.Text to be translated: "Edit"

编辑

8.Text to be translated: "Delete"

删除

9.Text to be translated: "Help"

帮助

10.Text to be translated: "Add account"

添加账户

11.Text to be translated: "Settings"

设置

12.Text to be translated: "Save"
保存

13.Text to be translated: "Copy"
复制

14.Text to be translated: "Cancel"
取消

15.Text to be translated: "Close"

关闭

16.Text to be translated: "Open website"

打开网址

17.Text to be translated: "New account"

新账户

18.Text to be translated: "Account name:"
账户名称

19.Text to be translated: "Internet address:"

网址

20.Text to be translated: "Password:"

密码

21.Text to be translated: "Edit account"
编辑账户

22.Text to be translated: "Password strength:"

密码长度

23.Text to be translated: "Account Name can not be empty!"
账户名称不能为空

24.Text to be translated: "Account added. Long click on it to edit"

账户已添加。长按编辑。

25.Text to be translated: "Password copied to clipboard"

密码已复制到剪贴板

26.Text to be translated: "Account deleted"

账户已删除

27.Text to be translated: "Account updated"

账户已更新

28.Text to be translated: "Preferences updated"

个人偏好已更新

Comment: Wow. You are really great. Thank you very much for your help. If you own an android phone, I would really love to get in touch with you and give you my application as a gift. You can contact me at the email displayed in my profile or trough gTalk(Hangouts) at the same address.

Comment: "Password strength" is 密码强度